# dart angular components OptionGroup:LabelFunction

Tags: angular, dart, angular-components

I'm playing with the new material-tree and wanted to pass a series of custom objects as a OptionGroup, these objects contain a label property which I need to enhance with a LabelFunction, but, this particular typedef doesn't accept any values, and simply is expected to output a String, I guess, I need an example or perhaps a sanity check as to my usage.
Given this simple class:

```
class pulsar {
  String label = '';
  String id = '';

  pulsar();
}
```

I'll like to create:

```
final SelectionOptions pulsars = new SelectionOptions([
    new OptionGroup.withLabelFunction(
        [pulsar1, pulsar2, pulsar3],
        (T) => labeler(T)
]);
// This is the problem, since the typedef String LabelFunction()
// Does not accept parameters.
// I will want this to work...
String labeler(pulsar p) => "${p.id} : ${p.label}";
```

I guess, I'm wondering if I'm missing the point of this **LabelFunction**..

Comment: Hi, I see you [went another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44711653/1416886) (with ItemRenderer). Does this make the question completely obsolete? Or do you still feel that other people might need LabelFunction?

Comment: Well, I'm afraid this question might come from my own ignorance with Angular and the new material-tree. But, I would like to know if this is even remotely possible...I mean, I can see how someone sees "withLabelFunction" and assumes "Aha!, I can pass my localization/regex/string-template/ect here!" and be confused on how to apply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I opted for an ItemRenderer.